# Save image in python 3.1

Tags: image, python-3.x, save

I have image data in buffer I want to save image in my computer by don't use library.
(I use python 3.1)
Thank you so much.

Comment: does python 3.x doesnot support open ?? if it do then `f = open('file', 'w'); f.write(imagedate);f.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in python 3.x the built in `open` function is aliased to `io.open` so you can do ( assuming you have image data stored in `imagedata`)

```
filename = "image.png"  # use suitable extension according to the format of the image
f = open(filename, 'w') # first argument is the filename
f.write(imagedate)
f.close()
```

Now the image will be saved in the local directory with file name `image.png`.

Comment: Huh? There is no such statement in PEP 3116.

Comment: @Lennart: Okay i agree but check this out http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-already-present-in-python-2-6  it is mentioned that now the new `io` module is the standard way to do I/O. which comes under PEP 3116

Comment: imagedate is buffer type can not write this.

Comment: then a quick and dirty way:  replace `f.write(imagedate)` with `f.write(imagedate.read())`

Comment: @Shiv: Yes, io is the new module for io. Nowhere is it recommended that you import open from io. That would be completey pointless, as open already is an alias for io.open so `from io import open` does exactly nothing.

Comment: @Lennart: the first line it says `The io module is now the standard way of doing file I/O`, i am insisting this fact that it is the standard way. I am not telling him that it is the only way to do i/o. And yes! I agree with you. `open` is the alias for `io.open` so it can be omitted. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Worked after I removed the single quotes around filename in the arguments to the open method